# retrieve an array in php after passing from angular js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs

I have an array like this

```
 $scope.kk =  [
        { name:'Computer Architecture', price:65 }, 
        { name:'Advanced Composite Materials', price:45 }, 
        { name:'Stategies Unplugged', price:43 }, 
        { name:'Teaching Science', price:50 }, 
        { name:'Challenging Times', price:22 }];
```

I have passed this array to my controller through webapi like this

```
     var req1= {
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: apiPoint.url + 'sin.php',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                       params :{
                           "fulldet[]" : $scope.kk
                       }
 $http(req1).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.status) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
}
}
```

And in my controller i need to extract this array
I have used foreach statement like this

```
$result['ppp'] = $fulldet;

foreach($fulldet as $e){
                $result['lm']=$e['name'];
            }
```

But am getting `ILLEGAL STRING OFFSET 'name'`
Please help me.

For my reference i hv printed my array back after the response from controller. I get it like this

```
{"ppp":["
            {\" name\":\"Computer Architecture\", \"price\":65 }, 
            {\" name\":\"Advanced Composite Materials\", \"price\":45 }, 
            { \"name\":\"Stategies Unplugged\", \"price\":43 }, 
            {\" name\":\"Teaching Science\", \"price\":50 }, 
            {\" name\":\"Challenging Times\", \"price\":22 }"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to iterate over array apply [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) to it.

```
$result['ppp'] = json_decode($fulldet, true);

foreach($fulldet as $e){
    $result['lm']=$e['name'];
}
```

Comment: it is giving warning like this json_decode()  expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Please post how do you receive data in php, it is not clear what is the problem. Sound like you have already parsed data.

Answer (score -1):

as i see now, your problem is when you try to get the data on the server side (sorry , for previous answer).

the parameter that you pass inside the request should be **string**  not **array**

so you change this:

```
params :{
                           "fulldet[]" : $scope.kk
                       }
```

to this:

```
 params :{
                           "fulldet" : $scope.kk
                       }
```

try to get your POST data like this:

```
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input),true);

foreach($results as $item){
   echo  $item['name'];
 }
```

Comment: thanks sir . but my actual problem is with controller.                           foreach($fulldet as $e){
                $result['lm']=$e['name'];
            }                    But am getting ILLEGAL STRING OFFSET 'name' . how to solve this??

Comment: have you tried to parse your data instead of stringify them? JSON.parse()

Comment: i have posted the data like this   headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                       params :{
                           "fulldet[]" : $scope.kk
                       }

Comment: it is giving warning like this json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: change your parameter from array to string:
this ->  "fulldet[]" : $scope.kk
to this ->  "fulldet" : $scope.kk
and you will be ready.

Comment: while i use fulldet" : $scope.kk , i will get only the last entry.     {"ppp":[" {\" name\":\"Challenging Times\", \"price\":22 }"].   Also same illegal offset name is showing

Comment: There is no 'ppp' , so when you try to get the data on the server just: 

foreach($results as $item){
   echo  $item['name'];
 }